# YouTrack REST API, get issue history

Tags: jetbrains-ide, youtrack, youtrack-api

I am trying get specific information about ticket activities.

I wanna know next things:

1. All assignee change events
2. All sprints change events
3. All story points change events
4. All status change events

I built next URL:

```
issue_history_activity_url = (f"{base_url}/issues/{issue_id}/activities?categories=CustomFieldCategory&fields=field(name),author(login),timestamp,added(name),removed(name)")
```

It gives me almost everything except the assignee change events. I tried every category [from documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/devportal/api-entity-ActivityCategory.html), nothing works.

Please help. GPT chat couldn't help too.

Answer (score 0):

I have found assignee in ProjectCategory custom fields.
It is really a little bit counterintuitively.